# How to convert a large number of 2D arrays (over 200k arrays) to 1D arrays in Google Apps Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I want to convert a large number of 2D arrays (over 200k arrays) to 1D arrays with Google Apps Script.   When the number of 2D data arrays is 120,000, the following codes are working well without any problem .  But they didn’t work when the number of arrays was 130,000.  Looks like some limitation in .concat method.  In my actual application, the error message returned "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".   Can anyone help?  Or is there a better method to get 1D array data directly from one column data in Google Sheets?  Thanks a lot for any recommendation!

```
function test() {
 
 var write = [];
 for (i = 0; i < 130000; ++i) {
   write[i] = ['AAPL'];
 }
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, write.length, 1).setValues(write);
 write = [];
 
 //The code below converts 2D array data to 1D successfully when the number of data arrays is 120000.
 var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:A120000').getValues();
 data = [].concat(...data);
 console.log(data.length);
 
 //The code below fails when the number of data arrays is 130000.
 var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:A130000').getValues();
 data = [].concat(...data);
 
}
```

Comment: try this: .getRange('A1:A120000').getValues().flat();

Comment: What a simple solution!   It works perfectly!   Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @RemcoE33 I'd advice to post your comment as an answer. And Newbie could to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.FLAT()**

```
.getRange('A1:A120000').getValues().flat();
```

Here is some [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

An IDE like visual studio code will know this as an array option. The online script editor does not give this as an option in autocomplete but it will works. Because the online IDE does not has this option inside his auto intelligence the editor will not know you working with arrays moving forward.